# Socket send data entered in Terminal

Tags: php, linux, sockets, terminal

I want to create a Socket that listens to connections and sends data which i enter in terminal (want  to run it using php script.php) to all Clients

any direction too look?

best regards, 
Jack

Comment: For websockets in PHP it would be best to use something already done. Have a look at Ratchet http://socketo.me/ its a library for websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script does what you want and also writes data sent by the clients to your terminal, run using `php script.php`:

```
<?php

$port = 12345;
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://localhost:$port", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$server) die("$errstr (errno $errno)\n");

$s = array(STDIN, $server); // initially wait for terminal input or connections
while ($r = $s and stream_select($r, $n=NULL, $n=NULL, NULL))
foreach ($r as $stream)
    if ($stream == STDIN)   // terminal input
    {
        $data = fgets(STDIN);
        foreach (array_slice($s, 2) as $client)     // clients from index 2 on
            fputs($client, $data);
    }
    else
    if ($stream == $server) // new client
        $s[] = stream_socket_accept($server, -1);   // add it to $s (index 2 on)
    else                    // data from a client
        if (!fputs(STDOUT, fgets($stream)))
        {
            fclose($stream);
            array_splice($s, array_search($stream, $s), 1); // remove client
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following program would help you in sending and receiving data.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);


$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);


$from = *Destination IP*;
$port = 50001;
$msg = "@SET0123014002";
$len = strlen($msg);

//for sending message
socket_sendto($socket, $msg, 0, 0, $from, $port);

print "Time: " . date("%r") . "\n";

socket_close($socket);

echo "$msg and $len was Sent<br>";

$socket1 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

//to Receive data from terminal.
socket_bind($socket1, '*Your System IP*', 50001);
socket_recvfrom($socket1, $buf, 12,0, $from, $port);

echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
```